# Accessing Session Data in Pojo/Restful Service

Tags: java, rest, session, global

I have a requirement to include a user's id on every logging statement in an existing system that is very large. The user's information is currently stored in the HttpSesssion which I can easily get from the HttpRequest in our sevlets. But I will need this information in all the other POJOs that are invoked as well.

I could pass this information around, but I'd rather not as I don't want to modify the signature of every method in our system as that would take too long and require too much testing.

Additionally, I will need the user's id when calling a Restful Service. I can easily pass that id on every request but again the amount of work to do this is undesireable.

What is the best practice for storing/receiving such "global" information? Preferably I'd like this information to be set once via our authentication logic and then be accessible from any other class (servlet, pojo, service, etc) within the JVM, including across Java applications (.war).

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the user information in [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). One of the ways to do that is to create a ServletFilter which will save the user info to ThreadLocal and remove it (very important!)  when request processing is done. All the methods that need user info then would read it from ThreadLocal variable.

To pass the user id with every Restful Service without changing all the code you would need some kind of Interceptor. If you are using spring, implementnig ClientHttpRequestInterceptor would be the way to go.